# Oracle Stored Procedure: Returning a Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure

In my stored procedure it needs to get inputs and return multiple rows to a front-end application.

However the stored Procedure produces an errors:

- SQL Statement ignored
- not enough values

How to resolve?

---

**Object type**

```
CREATE TYPE org_rspnsble_prsns_type 
    AS OBJECT (
    "appId" varchar2, 
    "orgId" varchar2, 
    "domainId" varchar2, 
    "leadName" varchar2, 
    "personId" number
);
```

**Table type**

```
CREATE TYPE org_rspnsble_prsns_table 
AS TABLE OF org_rspnsble_prsns_type;
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetNames( appIdInput IN varchar2, orgIdInput IN varchar2, p_arr OUT org_rspnsble_prsns_table )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT "appId", "orgId", "domainId", "leadName", "personId"
    BULK COLLECT INTO p_arr
    FROM (
        select "appId", "orgId", "domainId", "leadName", "personId"
        from tableA
    UNION
        select "appId", "orgId", "domainId", "leadName", "personId"
        from tableB
    )
    WHERE "appId" = appIdInput
    AND "orgId" = orgIdInput;
END;
```

Comment: Try to avoid `" "` from everywhere.

Comment: When do you get the error ? When you create the procedure or when you call it ?

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, yes when I create the Procedure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good way to do it from:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551171813078805685

```
create or replace package types 
as 
    type cursorType is ref cursor; 
end; 
/
create or replace function sp_ListEmp return types.cursortype 
as 
    l_cursor    types.cursorType; 
begin 
    open l_cursor for select ename, empno from emp order by ename;
    return l_cursor; 
end; 
/
create or replace procedure getemps( p_cursor in out types.cursorType )
as
begin
open p_cursor for select ename, empno from emp order by ename;
end;
/
```

Thank you to all who answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your SELECT select 5 columns into 1 variable. You have to either
A) create object in your select:

```
SELECT org_rspnsble_prsns_type("appId", "orgId", "domainId", "leadName", "personId")
BULK COLLECT INTO p_arr
...
```

or B) create the type as record:

```
CREATE TYPE org_rspnsble_prsns_type 
AS RECORD (...
```